# Joining two or more selected values in one span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to combine select options in one span using jQuery or JavaScript.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <label>Product:</label> 
    <select id='Product' value='Product'>
        <option value=" " selected>--Select your Product--</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>           
    </select>

    <label>Subproduct:</label> <select id='SubProd' value='SubProd'>

    <option value=" " selected>--Select your Subproduct--</option>
        <option>Sub 1</option>
        <option>Sub 2</option>
     </select>
     <br>
     <span id="joined"></span>
</body>
```

In the `span` I want show `Product1/Sub1` depending on the option selected. I've been searching but I can't find something useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `change` event to get real-time updated values. and you can directly use `$("#Product").val()` to get the value instead of `option:selected`, because `change` event would always give you updated value:

```js
$("#Product, #SubProd").on('change', function() {
  $("#joined").text($("#Product").val() + "/" + $("#SubProd").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Product:</label> <select id='Product' value='Product'>

<option value=" " selected>--Select your Product--</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>           
      </select>

<label>Subproduct:</label> <select id='SubProd' value='SubProd'>

<option value=" " selected>--Select your Subproduct--</option>
        <option>Sub 1</option>
        <option>Sub 2</option>
      </select>
<br>
<span id="joined"></span>
```

Comment: Thank You very much, at first was not working, but i did a little modification to the function an works perfectly :D

         $(function(){ 
            $('#Product, #SubProd').change(function() {
            $('#joined').text($('#Product').val() + "/" + $('#SubProd').val());});});

Answer (score 1):

Although your question seems a little unclear,check if this works

```
$('#Product,#SubProd').on('change',function(){
       $('#joined').html( $('#Product').find('option:selected').text() + "/" + $('#SubProd').find('option:selected').text());
});
```

ps: You will need to have some checking condition to prevent displaying the "Select an option" tag.